# Number format exception in compojure

Tags: clojure, compojure, numberformatexception

As total clojure noob, I am trying to start one small tutorial app, in order to get familiar with compojure. It's a small application which lets user add two numbers, and after clicking on button displays their sum on the other page. I followed instruction from Mark [McGranaghan blog](http://mmcgrana.github.com/2010/07/develop-deploy-clojure-web-applications.html). Everything seems ok, until I try to get sum of two numbers I have entered, instead of getting result, I am redirected to the same page (so basically I am stuck on first step of this tutorial). After checking the code, it seems that NumberFormatException is triggered when input parsing takes place (for some reason). In all my tests, I have tried to input all kinds of number format , but with no success. Here is the simplest code version , for which author said should work (I have tried the latest version from [github site](https://github.com/mmcgrana/adder.git)- same scenario: NFE):

```
    (ns adder.core
  (:use compojure.core)
  (:use hiccup.core)
  (:use hiccup.page-helpers))

(defn view-layout [& content]
  (html
    (doctype :xhtml-strict)
    (xhtml-tag "en"
      [:head
        [:meta {:http-equiv "Content-type"
                :content "text/html; charset=utf-8"}]
        [:title "adder"]]
      [:body content])))

(defn view-input []
  (view-layout
    [:h2 "add two numbers"]
    [:form {:method "post" :action "/"}
      [:input.math {:type "text" :name "a"}] [:span.math " + "]
      [:input.math {:type "text" :name "b"}] [:br]
      [:input.action {:type "submit" :value "add"}]]))

(defn view-output [a b sum]
  (view-layout
    [:h2 "two numbers added"]
    [:p.math a " + " b " = " sum]
    [:a.action {:href "/"} "add more numbers"]))

(defn parse-input [a b] ;; this is the place where problem occures
  [(Integer/parseInt a) (Integer/parseInt b)])

(defroutes app
  (GET "/" []
    (view-input))

  (POST "/" [a b]
    (let [[a b] (parse-input a b)
          sum   (+ a b)]
      (view-output a b sum)))
```

Can anyone tell me better way to pars the input values, in order to avoid this exception?I have tried couple of techniques , but nothing worked for me. I am using Leningen v1.7.1 with clojure 1.3 on win 7 machine.

Here is content of my project.clj file:

```
(defproject adder "0.0.1"
  :description "Add two numbers."
  :dependencies
    [[org.clojure/clojure "1.3.0"]
     [org.clojure/clojure-contrib "1.1.0"]
     [ring/ring-core "1.0.2"]
     [ring/ring-devel "1.0.2"]
     [ring/ring-jetty-adapter "1.0.2"]
     [compojure "1.0.1"]
     [hiccup "0.3.8"]]
  :dev-dependencies
    [[lein-run "1.0.0"]])
```

and run.clj script:

```
(use 'ring.adapter.jetty)
(require 'adder.core)

(let [port (Integer/parseInt (get (System/getenv) "PORT" "8080"))]
  (run-jetty #'adder.core/app {:port port}))
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using compojure 1.0.1, the example in the blog you are following is using compojure 0.4.0.

> As of version 0.6.0, Compojure no longer adds default middleware to routes. This means you must explicitly add the wrap-params and wrap-cookies middleware to your routes.

Source: https://github.com/weavejester/compojure

So you need to explicitly add the wrap-params middleware. So the following changes are required...

```
(ns adder.core
  (:use                    ; change to idiomatic usage of :use
    [compojure.core] 
    [hiccup.core]
    [hiccup.page-helpers]
    [ring.middleware.params :only [wrap-params]])) ; add middleware for params

(defn view-layout [& content]
  (html
    (doctype :xhtml-strict)
    (xhtml-tag "en"
          [:head
           [:meta {:http-equiv "Content-type"
                   :content "text/html; charset=utf-8"}]
           [:title "adder"]]
          [:body content])))

(defn view-input []
    (view-layout
     [:h2 "add two numbers"]
     [:form {:method "post" :action "/"}
     [:input.math {:type "text" :name "a" :id "a"}] [:span.math " + "]
     [:input.math {:type "text" :name "b" :id "a"}] [:br]
     [:input.action {:type "submit" :value "add"}]]))

(defn view-output [a b sum]
  (view-layout
   [:h2 "two numbers added"]
   [:p.math a " + " b " = " sum]
   [:a.action {:href "/"} "add more numbers"]))

(defn parse-input [a b]
  [(Integer/parseInt a) (Integer/parseInt b)])

(defroutes main-routes             ; needs to be renamed
   (GET "/" []
      (view-input))

   (POST "/" [a b]
      (let [[a b] (parse-input a b)
          sum   (+ a b)]
      (view-output a b sum))))

(def app (wrap-params main-routes)) ; wrap the params to allow destructuring to work
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I will try this as soon as I can.